# Не могу понять почему данные сохраняться от рандомного процесса, пробовал , lock и menegor но все безуспешно. Python,openpyxl, Seenium

Tags: python, selenium, openpyxl

Нужно что бы данные из каждого процесса сохранялись в свою колонку, в одном файле Excel.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`введите сюда код`
import datetime
import random

def funk(qwer0, qwer1, qwer2, qwer3, qwer4, lock):

service = Service(r"C:\Users\...\chromedriver.exe")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument('user-data-dir=' + qwer0)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomaionControlled')
options.add_argument(
    'user-agent=...')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

try:
    current_date = datetime.date.today().isoformat()

    fn = 't.baza.xlsx'
    wb = load_workbook(fn)
    ws = wb['Лист1']

    driver.get(r'https://www.google.com/search?')
    time.sleep(3)

    href = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'qLRx3b.tjvcx.GvPZzd.cHaqb')

    for a in href:
        ada = a.text
        print(ada)
        with lock:
            ws.cell(row=ws.max_row + 1, column=qwer2).value = ada
            ws.cell(row=ws.max_row, column=qwer2+1).value = current_date
            wb.save(fn)



    print('СТОП')
    wb.save(fn)
    wb.close()
    time.sleep(5)

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    #lock.release()
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
with Manager() as manager:
    lock = manager.Lock()
    qwer4 = [int(0), int(-1), int(-1), int(-1), int(-1), int(-1), int(-1), int(-1)]
    qwer3 = [('A'), ('C'), ('E'), ('G'), ('I'), ('K'), ('M'), ('O')]
    qwer2 = [int(1), int(3), int(5), int(7), int(9), int(11), int(13), int(15)]
    qwer1 = [.....]
    qwer0 = [.....]

    qwe = [(qwer0[0], qwer1[0], qwer2[0], qwer3[0], qwer4[0], lock),
           (qwer0[1], qwer1[1], qwer2[1], qwer3[1], qwer4[1], lock),
           (qwer0[2], qwer1[2], qwer2[2], qwer3[2], qwer4[2], lock),
           (qwer0[3], qwer1[3], qwer2[3], qwer3[3], qwer4[3], lock)]
           # (qwer0[4], qwer1[4], qwer2[4], qwer3[4], qwer4[4], lock),
           # (qwer0[5], qwer1[5], qwer2[5], qwer3[5], qwer4[5], lock)]
    # (qwer0[6], qwer1[6], qwer2[6], qwer3[6], qwer4[6]),
    # (qwer0[7], qwer1[7], qwer2[7], qwer3[7], qwer4[7])]

    while True:
        pool = Pool(processes=4)
        pool.starmap(funk, qwe)
```

Comment: зачем создавать себе трудности? каждый процесс сохранил себе свой csv, потом следует обьединить все "заработанное честным трудом" в единый xlsx

Comment: далее, изменение файла - медленная операция, проще занести получаемые данные в shared-массив и потом уже выгрузить в xlsx

Comment: Прочитайте заголовок своего вопроса - вам тоже кажется, что это какой-то набор слов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данные сохраняются от рандомного процесса, потому что вы открываете и закрываете `workbook` вне `lock`-а. Это бессмысленно. У вас в файле останутся данные того экселя, который будет закрыт последним, потому что они все перезаписывают результаты друг друга. Хотите консистентности - оборачивайте полностью работу с `workbook` в `lock`, начиная с открытия и до закрытия. Правда, это убьёт почти всю выгоду от многопоточности.

На мой взгляд лучше сделать так, учитывая то, что писать в файл многопоточно - затея довольно бессмысленная, оптимизации так не достигнуть:

- В каждом процессе собирайте нужную вам инфу в список и возвращайте этот список (и параметры вызова функции) через `return`. В `workbook` в процессах не пишите.
- Итерируйтесь по результату работы `pool.starmap(...)`, это даст вам по очереди возвращаемые из процессов результаты.
- Итерируйтесь по каждому из полученных списков и, с учётом параметров вызова, записывайте результат в `workbook` в нужные поля.

Таким образом, у вас будет многопоточное получение данных (ведь оно самое ресурсозатратное) и однопоточная запись результатов в эксель - в основном потоке.